# Reassigning Elements of Array: Syntax (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, syntax, assignment-operator, parallel-assignment

I'm learning the parallel assignment operator in Ruby now. When I tried using it to swap values in an array, I got unexpected results. Couldn't find the answer to this online and was hoping someone can shed the light on what is happening here.

First example:

```
array = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
array[0,1] = array[1,0] 
=> []
array
=> [2, 3] #thought this would be = [2,1,3]
```

Where did array[0] go and why wouldn't Ruby swap the values?

Second example:

```
array = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
array[0,1] = [1,0]
=> [1, 0]
array
=> [1, 0, 2, 3] #was expecting [1,0,3]
```

Why did Ruby insert the right hand side into array and not substitute the values?

Comment: First check what `array[1,0]` does alone -- returns `[]`  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D  You are using the `Array[start, length]` notation, so the premise of swapping elements with that notation is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `array[0,1]` syntax is picking a slice of the array starting at `0` and of length `1`. Longer slices make that more obvious.

```
> a = [1,2,3]
 => [1,2,3]
> a[0,2]
 => [1, 2]
```

To swap the way you want in your first example, you need to specify both indices independently.

```
> a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
 => [2, 1]
> a
 => [2, 1, 3]
```

In your second example, Ruby replaces the `array[0,1]` slice with `[1, 0]`, effectively removing the first element and inserting the new `[1, 0]`. Changing to `array[0], array[1] = [1, 0]` will fix that for you too.

Comment: Terrific, thanks for the explanation. Now all makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

Parallel assignment involves specifying multiple variables on the left-hand side of the operator - your first attempt was close, but not quite what I believe you intended to do.  In order to get the behavior you expected, you'd need to write:

`array[0], array[1] = array[1], array[0]`

In contrast, you are writing `array[0, 1]`, which effectively refers to a "slice" of the array as one object.

Comment: Totally misunderstood what array[0,1] meant. Thanks!